# R: Creating a Function For Calculating Conditional Probabilities

Tags: r, function

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following data - suppose this contains the "exam results" for different students (same ID corresponds to the same student) taken at different times:

```
id = sample.int(10000, 100000, replace = TRUE)
res = c("PASS", "FAIL")
results = sample(res, 100000, replace = TRUE)
date_exam_taken = sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 100000, replace = TRUE)

my_data = data.frame(id, results, date_exam_taken)
my_data <- my_data[order(my_data$id, my_data$date_exam_taken),]

      id results date_exam_taken
43894  1    FAIL      2001-06-18
31309  1    FAIL      2001-10-21
1996   1    FAIL      2004-08-21
76256  1    PASS      2004-10-13
14043  1    PASS      2005-05-11
38423  1    FAIL      2006-06-10
```

I want to answer the following question - based on this data, given a that student failed their 3rd exam, what is the probability that a student will pass their 4th exam and what is the probability that this student will fail their 4th exam?

In other words - **given the result of the nth exam, what is the probability of pass/fail their n+1 th exam?**

I tried to answer this in the following way:

```
my_data$general_id = 1:nrow(my_data)
my_data$exam_number = ave(my_data$general_id, my_data$id, FUN = seq_along)
my_data$general_id = NULL

third_exam = my_data[which(my_data$exam_number == 3), ]
third_exam = third_exam[which(third_exam$results == "FAIL"), ]
fourth_exam = my_data[which(my_data$exam_number == 4), ]

merged = merge(x = third_exam, y = fourth_exam, by = "id", all = TRUE)
merged = na.omit(merged)

pass = merged[merged$results.x == 'FAIL' & merged$results.y  == "PASS", ]
fail = merged[merged$results.x == 'FAIL' & merged$results.y  == "FAIL", ]

pass_prob = nrow(pass)/(nrow(pass) + nrow(fail))
fail_prob = nrow(fail)/(nrow(pass) + nrow(fail))
```

I tried to make this into a function for the future:

```
my_function <- function(current_exam, next_exam, result_of_current_exam)
    
{

my_data$general_id = 1:nrow(my_data)
my_data$exam_number = ave(my_data$general_id, my_data$id, FUN = seq_along)
my_data$general_id = NULL
    
    c_exam = my_data[which(my_data$exam_number == current_exam), ]
    c_exam = c_exam[which(c_exam$results == result_of_current_exam), ]
    n_exam = my_data[which(my_data$exam_number == next_exam), ]
    
    merged = merge(x = c_exam, y = n_exam, by = "id", all = TRUE)
    merged = na.omit(merged)
    
    pass = merged[merged$results.x == result_of_current_exam & merged$results.y  == "PASS", ]
    fail = merged[merged$results.x == result_of_current_exam & merged$results.y  == "FAIL", ]
    
    pass_prob = nrow(pass)/(nrow(pass) + nrow(fail))
    fail_prob = nrow(fail)/(nrow(pass) + nrow(fail))
    
    return(c(pass_prob, fail_prob))
    
}
```

Now to call the function - given a student passed the third exam, what are the probabilities of passing and failing the fourth exam?

```
> my_function("3","4", "PASS")
[1] 0.5126595 0.4873405
```

- I am now trying to run this function for all consecutive combinations (e.g. probabilities for the results of 2nd exam given 1st,  probabilities for the results of 3rd exam given 2nd, probabilities for the results of 4th exam given 3rd, etc.).
- I would also be interested in extending this function - given the results of the first and the second exam (e.g. FAIL, FAIL), what are the probabilities for the results of the third exam?

Is there a quick way to apply my function (assuming I have written this function correctly) for all these combinations?

**Can someone please show me how to do this correctly?**

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check your code? `my_function("3","4", "PASS")` returns `NaN NaN` for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second question, here’s a function that takes multiple conditions, passed as a named vector:

```
set.seed(13)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

conditional_rates <- function(conditions, next_exam) {
  conditioned <- my_data %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    filter(
      all(map2_lgl(
        as.numeric(names(conditions)),
        conditions,
        ~ any(row_number() == .x & results == .y)
      )),
      row_number() == next_exam
    ) %>%
    ungroup()
    
  p_PASS <- mean(conditioned$results == "PASS")
  
  c(p_PASS = p_PASS, p_FAIL = 1 - p_PASS)
}

# rates for exam 4 conditional on passing exam 3
conditional_rates(c("3" = "PASS"), 4)
#    p_PASS    p_FAIL 
# 0.4908248 0.5091752 

# rates for exam 4 conditional on failing exams 1 
# and 3 and passing exam 2
conditional_rates(
  c("1" = "FAIL", "2" = "PASS", "3" = "FAIL"),
  4
)
#    p_PASS    p_FAIL 
# 0.4946483 0.5053517
```

Answer (score 2):

I attempted your first query regarding running the function for all consecutive combinations. Hope this is useful

```
current<-unique(my_data$exam_number)
next_ex<-current[-1]
current<-current[-length(current)]

library(tidyverse)
pmap(list(.x=current,.y=next_ex),
     ~my_function(current_exam=.x,
                  next_exam=.y,
                  result_of_current_exam="PASS"))

pmap(list(.x=current,.y=next_ex),
     ~my_function(current_exam=.x,
                  next_exam=.y,
                  result_of_current_exam="FAIL"))
```

Comment: @ Chris. Jude : Thank you for your answer! If you have time, can you please show an example as to how someone would "call" your function? E.g. how would I use it? Thank you so much!

Comment: @ Chris.Jude: In general, would you say the code I have written (for this specific problem) is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`, we can simply `shift` the results and aggregate by exam number. Here is a function that will allow you to specify how many tests to look back using the `lag` argument.

```
library(data.table)

fExams <- function(dt, lag = 1L) {
  nms <- c("exam_num", paste0("prev", lag:1))
  dt2 <- setorderv(
    dt[
      ,(nms) := c(.(1:.N), lapply(lag:1, function(i) shift(results, i))), id
    ][
      ,.(prob_pass = mean(results == "PASS"), samples = .N),
      # exam_num:prev1
      nms
    ],
    nms
  )
  dt[,(nms) := NULL]
  dt2
}
```

Get the first 15 rows of the table that looks three exams back.

```
fExams(dt, 3)[1:15]
#>     exam_num prev3 prev2 prev1 prob_pass samples
#>  1:        1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 0.4950495    9999
#>  2:        2  <NA>  <NA>  FAIL 0.5031708    5046
#>  3:        2  <NA>  <NA>  PASS 0.5014141    4950
#>  4:        3  <NA>  FAIL  FAIL 0.5063949    2502
#>  5:        3  <NA>  FAIL  PASS 0.4922894    2529
#>  6:        3  <NA>  PASS  FAIL 0.5002030    2463
#>  7:        3  <NA>  PASS  PASS 0.4915391    2482
#>  8:        4  FAIL  FAIL  FAIL 0.4861338    1226
#>  9:        4  FAIL  FAIL  PASS 0.4904459    1256
#> 10:        4  FAIL  PASS  FAIL 0.5094192    1274
#> 11:        4  FAIL  PASS  PASS 0.5169355    1240
#> 12:        4  PASS  FAIL  FAIL 0.5000000    1222
#> 13:        4  PASS  FAIL  PASS 0.4930271    1219
#> 14:        4  PASS  PASS  FAIL 0.4763432    1247
#> 15:        4  PASS  PASS  PASS 0.5282392    1204
```

We can see from row 12 that exactly 50% of the 1222 students who passed their first exam but failed their second and third also failed their fourth exam.

For more general queries, here is a function that returns p(y|x), where x is the results of exams to condition on and y is the results of exams of interest.

```
pExam <- function(dt, x, y) {
  yRes <- c("FAIL", "PASS")[sign(y)/2 + 1.5]
  i <- with(
    rle(
      sort(
        dt[,exam_num := 1:.N, id][
          .(
            exam_num = abs(x),
            results = c("FAIL", "PASS")[sign(x)/2 + 1.5]
          ),
          on = .(exam_num = exam_num, results = results)
        ]$id
      )
    ),
    values[lengths == length(x)]
  )
  mean(dt[id %in% i & exam_num %in% y][,identical(results, yRes), id][[2]])
}
```

As with the previous example, the proportion of students who passed their fourth exam given that they passed their first exam but failed their second and third exams is:

```
pExam(dt, c(1, -2, -3), 4)
#> [1] 0.5
```

Here a negative index in `x` or `y` indicates a failed exam.

Data:

```
set.seed(1238818837)

dt <- setkey(
  data.table(
    id = sample.int(10000, 100000, replace = TRUE),
    results = sample(c("PASS", "FAIL"), 100000, replace = TRUE),
    date_exam_taken = sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('2020/01/01'), by="day"), 100000, replace = TRUE)
  ),
  id, date_exam_taken
)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! Is it possible to add "-2" and use it to calculate probability of passing the next exam based on the previous 2 exams? Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure thing. I don't think I fully understood your question the first time through, but I think I've got it now. See the update.

Comment: Updated again with a function `pExam` that handles more specific queries.